# How to know embed's text and author in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was trying to find the way you can identify embed message text and author, but never found it. So is there any way to do that?

Googled through out of the Internet but not found it unfortunately.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#embed)

If you have an Embed object, `obj` just use `obj.author` to get the author. The text I'm assuming you mean the title, which can be accessed by `obj.title`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `Message` object,

First, to get message author:

```py
author = message.author
```

To get the embed from the message:

```py
embed = discord.Embed.from_data(message.embeds[0])  # gets embed from message
```

Before getting the embed text, we first look at the attributes of a `discord.Embed` object. It has the attributes `title` and `description` [[source]](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#embed).

Therefore:

```py
embedTitle = embed.title  # get title
embedDescription = embed.description  # get description
```